# Can web browser read hall sensor as input like a mouse click?

Tags: javascript, android, input, browser, webbrowser-control

sorry if this question sound totally dumb. May i know if it is possible to use hall sensor as input device, simulating a mouse click on android web browser?
For example, i open a web browser in Android device, (device connect to hall sensor, maybe via a usb cable ) when a hall sensor detect magnet presence, web browser take it as a mouse click.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by coding a browser app sensible to hall sensor yes but your website can't detect himself the hall sensor sorry :(. If you can code in android you can make that your browser simulates a mouse click with the hall sensor.